# Solution to provide shared entities between multiple Java processes

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, nosql

I am trying to reconstruct a flow of information from multiple parts handled by different Java processes. Please note that i don't generate the flows, i just read some information about them.

I've tried using MySQL (MyISAM/InnoDB tables) with INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE using an id for each flow. I've also tried storing all the pieces of information and running a query at the end to get the full information. Neither of these approaches yielded the performance needed.

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to have a set of shared objects between multiple Java processes. The objects should be persistent between runs and fast to lookup/update concurrently (>100k lookups/updates per second).

I've thought of a few solutions including:

- NoSQL: something like MongoDB, HBase etc.
- a caching solution like EhCache, Memcached etc.

The problem is i don't have any experience with any of these solutions. So, what would you recommend that fits the following criteria:

- very fast on a single system. Most of the applications i mentioned were built for distributed systems, but it's not the case here.
- easy to learn/use (i want to be able to prototype it in a day)
- mature technology
- free to use even for commercial purposes
- preferably open-source

Comment: I suspect you won't get 100K updates per second from these libraries. I have written a faster library but it only supports one writer and it requires a very good understanding of how data is laid out in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a seperate java process that co-ordinates between the others.  This process would hold the information to pass over to the main processes.  You could wire them up with RMI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do only exchange of objects withing java applications, you could also looki into tuple spaces. There are specific implementations of spaces for java, JavaSpaces, which should be able to do what you need. Not sure if they can keep up with the performance though. Also I’m not sure how widely this technology is still being used, since it only supports Java and isn’t as flexible as NoSQL stores would be these days.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space#JavaSpaces) has a more detailed description and list of different implementations, many of which are open source.

The other option is to go with Redis, you have notifications there and it can for sure scale to the requirements you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The old (legacy?) solution is JavaSpaces. However, from an software architects point of view I would say distributed caches are the replacements for that nowadays. Especially take a look at hazelcast and infinispan.

From the performance viewpoint I am not happy with the performance of the "big" distributed caching solutions, when only a single in-memory cache is needed, see my writeup on the [cache2k benchmarks](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html) page (hazelcast needs to be added here).

Anyways, please clarify your problem statement first, because your question falls into the [XyProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) category. You are not describing the actual problem, and your question just boils down to "fast reliable distributed objects" solution. What kind of data comes in? What is the rate? Who is it accessed? What consistency guarantees need to be met, considering the fact that writing and reading is in parallel?

By the term "flow of information" it sounds more like a [complex event processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing) problem to me.